# Reload only specific input fields of parent page after close child page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have HTML form where I open a new popup and insert some data and refresh the
complete page and close the popup.

But my problem is: I want to refresh only specific input field data not whole page.

Kindly also send some links for details and demo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you will have to use AJAX in that case

Comment: Use Ajax to refresh a specific input field

Comment: Kindly send me some links for demo. because i am new to use ajax.

Comment: https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/ajax/ http://www.9lessons.info/2009/05/jquery-and-ajax-best-demos.html http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-ajax-example/

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax (maybe jquery, if you are already using it)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://url_to_get_input_field_data",
}).done(function( data ) {
    $("input_field_id").val(data);
});
```